# UITableView button image disappears while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` (like FaceBook post where I want to like, share, comment). When I click one like button it should turn to some other image and also it should call a method for further process.
I am using `Objective-C`

Comment: What have you tried? Please show the parts of your code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Storyboard`, just change the `Button properties` for different **`State Configurations`** according to your requirement.

[image]

According to your requirement, you need to set the different `Image property` for both `Default and Selected states`.

No need to write any extra lines of code for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with set image for State Config of button `[Normal, Highlighted, Selected, Disable]` at design.
When you click on the button, you call a method and change state of button **Selected** or None.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like it's because of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method. In `cellForRowAtIndexpath`, you need to check button is clicked in this cell or not.

If button in this cell is clicked, set image of button with `clicked image`. If not, set image of button with `normal image`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set images for different states like below

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"] forState:UIControlStateHighlightedSelected];
```